# D3JS execution order of Force layout start,tick

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am using d3.js. But I am unable to understand **how force.tick executes (i.e implicitly or explicitly)**. Please try to give the idea about the execution order of start, tick and end. **What is the Usage and Impacts of these events?** 
Also when I use something like this:

```
force.start();
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) force.tick();
force.stop();
```

**How it generates a static image?**

P.S: This is the first time I am posting a question. Please inform if any thing is against the guideline.

Program Sample:

```
   var k=0;
   force.on("tick",tick);
   force.start();//now tick will execute until the alpha lowers to the threshold value
   function tick()
   {
    k++;
   }
```

the ultimate value of 'k' depends how long the alpha is greater than threshold value.

Now suppose,

```
var k=0;
force.on("tick",tick);
force.start();//now tick will execute until the alpha lowers to the threshold value
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
force.tick();
force.stop();
function tick()
{
k++;
}
```

Now I am getting the value of 'k' is '100'

In first case the tick() was getting called implicitly but now when it is called explicitly how the execution order get changed.

Answer (score 4):

The force layout works like this:

- `.start()` starts the simulation. Before it is called, nothing happens.
- `.tick()` advances the simulation by one time step. That is, the forces on the nodes are calculated and their positions based on those forces.
- `.stop()` stops the simulation. Nothing happens after it has been called.

The way the code you've posted generates a static layout is that the simulation is run for a number of time steps (`n`) and then stopped. Usually, `.stop()` isn't called explicitly, so the simulation never truly stops, just settles into an equilibrium state where no nodes move anymore.

So to recap -- the simulation is started, run for `n` steps and stopped. All of this happens before the page is rendered, so you don't see anything moving. If you increase `n` to a very large value, you should notice a lag before the page is rendered.

Comment: so is it that the "start" call the "tick" implicitly. if yes then what difference does it create when we call "tick" explicitly??

Comment: The simulation calls `.tick()`, not the `.start()` function itself. If you're calling it explicitly you're explicitly advancing the simulation by one step. You can think of it as a counter that's incremented every second or so, but that you can also increment explicitly.

Comment: I have updated the question to specify what I am trying to ask. Please check.

Comment: The execution order in both cases is the same -- one tick gets called after the other.

Comment: Thanks Lars Kotthoff.I think I got it what is happening. I am assuming that  when the tick() is not called explicitly it goes till the threshold value. I case of a explicit call the tick() will be executed based on the user specification [well force.stop() is needed to put the restriction on the tick() execution]. If I am assuming it in wrong way then please inform. 

**P.S. Thanks for helping out.**

Comment: There is no threshold by default, i.e. `.tick()` will be called without limit -- it's just that after a while it won't do much, so you don't see the effect. By calling `.stop()`, you're telling the force layout not to call `.tick()` anymore. You can however still call it explicitly, even after the force layout has been stopped.

Comment: calling tick explicitly is helpful to run the simulation without showing the graph: it updates positions up to a point, then you can draw the graph. Calling start to run the simulation is usually linked with refreshing the graph rendering at each tick. Using 'background' ticks helps for rendering huge graphs that would otherwise look very messy for a while.